# SQL convert int to time

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, time, int

I have a database that displays time as an integer. However I am wanting to output this into a report with the correct format. This is the format that I would like to change:

eg.

- `183000` would become `18:30`
- `500` would become    `00:05`
- `160000` would become `16:00`

and so on.

I have had a look and CAST and CONVERT but not successfully managed to get this the time in the correct format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your input will always be an int, you can parse it with something like:

```
DECLARE @stringTime varchar(6)

SET @stringTime =  RIGHT('000000' + CAST(intTime AS VARCHAR), 6)

SELECT CAST(LEFT(@stringTime, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(LEFT(@stringTime, 4), 2) AS TIME) as TimeValue
```

I'd DEFINITELY look to change this field to an actual time or datetime field, as this level of conversion is not advised, especially for a heavily used database. There's just really got to be a better way to store your data.

Using an int value this way allows for a lot of bad data, without adding a lot of additional checks and/or constraints on your inputs (i.e.: 260000, 127900, etc.)

Answer (score 3):

looks like you need to divide by 100 to get the seconds, divide by 10000 to get the minutes, and divide by 1000000 to get the hours, then format those values as a string, inserting a colon between hours and minutes, like

> hh:mm

Comment: +1 for no string parsing (which is probably what I would have done)

Answer (score 2):

First cast to a varchar field and convert all times to 4 digits adding leading zeros if need be (500 would become 0500)and then break up the field with concantenation Left(myfield,2) + ':' + right(myfield,2)

This is something stupid to do every time you run a report, it is wasteful of server resources. If possible change the field to varchar and runthe code once. If not possible, can you add a formatted field and have a trigger do the formatiing on insertion (you'll still need to update the field the first time? Possibly a constraint would do instead of a trigger, but that would depend on the database.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you are on SQL Server based on use of `CONVERT` and your previous questions.

You could use `DATEADD` for this too.

```
WITH Times AS
(
SELECT 183000 AS T 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 500 
UNION ALL  
SELECT 160000 

)
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, T%100 + (60*(T%10000 / 100)) + 3600*(T/10000),0)
            AS time /*Or datetime if < SQL Server 2008*/)
FROM Times
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @i int = 235959

select cast(stuff(stuff(
                case when len(cast(@i as varchar(6))) = 6 then cast(@i as varchar(6)) 
                     else REPLICATE('0',6 - LEN(cast(@i as varchar(6))))+cast(@i as varchar(6)) 
                end
            ,3,0,':'), 6, 0,':') as datetime)

set @i = 500

select cast(stuff(stuff(
                case when len(cast(@i as varchar(6))) = 6 then cast(@i as varchar(6)) 
                     else REPLICATE('0',6 - LEN(cast(@i as varchar(6))))+cast(@i as varchar(6)) 
                end
            ,3,0,':'), 6, 0,':') as datetime)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @intTime int
SET @intTime = 50000
SELECT CAST(STUFF(STUFF(CONCAT(REPLICATE('0', 6 - LEN(@intTime)),@intTime),3,0,':'),6,0,':') AS TIME(0))
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28383040)

Answer (score 0):

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[MinutesToDuration]
(
    @minutes int 
)
RETURNS nvarchar(30)

AS
BEGIN
declare @hours  nvarchar(20)
DECLARE @XX NVARCHAR(10) 
DECLARE @HH  VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @TT  VARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @BL   NVARCHAR(2)
DECLARE @TM  VARCHAR(5)

SET @XX=@minutes
IF @XX<60
    BEGIN
    IF @XX<10
        BEGIN
        SET @HH='00'
        SET @TT='0'+@XX
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
        SET @HH='00'
        SET @TT=@XX
        END
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    IF @XX%60=0
    BEGIN
    SET @HH=@XX/60
    SET @TT='00'
    END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @BL= @XX%60
            IF @BL<10
                BEGIN
                SET @HH=@XX/60
                SET @TT='0'+@BL
                END     
            ELSE
                BEGIN
                SET @HH=@XX/60
                SET @TT=@BL
                END
        END
END

SET @hours= @HH+':'+@TT

return @hours
END
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).